# What is the difference between the `data` and `json` named arguments with requests.post?

Tags: python, python-requests

According to the relevant portion of the [requests library documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), the primary method to pass a dictionary to the post method is as follows:

```
r = requests.post(url, data = {"example": "request"})
```

Afterwards, the authors demonstrate an example of passing a JSON string directly to the Github API. Then the authors suggest that instead of encoding the dictionary as a JSON string and passing it via `data`, you can simply use the named parameter `json` to pass a dictionary in as follows.

```
r= requests.post(url, json = {"example": "request"})
```

When would you use `json` instead of `data`? Is this redundancy idiosyncratic or intentional?

Comment: It can be possible if some server not accepting a particular format. Otherwise I don't find any reasoning to choose a particular option.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Passing a `dict` to `data` causes the `dict` to be *form-encoded*, as though you were submitting a form on an HTML page; e.g., `data={"example": "request"}` will be sent in the request body as `example=request`.  The `json` keyword, on the other hand, encodes its argument as a JSON value instead (and also sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The difference in request type (urlencoding vs  a text stream deserialized as json) was not obvious IMO, nor was the shift in header value apparent. I still wonder, when would you use the legacy `data` variable nowadays, aside from backwards-compatibility issues? AFAIK `json` is not recognized as far back as requests 2.0.0.

Comment: @W4t3randWind: If you only ever need to send JSON, backwards compatibility is indeed the only reason to use `data`, but there are still a number of servers and APIs that require request bodies to be some non-JSON format, e.g., InfluxDB or anything XML-based.

Answer (score 2):

From the `requests` documentation, it seems that `data` was meant to be used for form submission, hence it is built to expect `dict` datatype and will process objects passed to this variable into a `dict` type if it can.

For example, if a nested `json` is passed to `data`:

```
{
      "ticker_symbol":ticker,
      "model_type":"2",
      "prediction":[
        {
          "epoch_time": 11111100000,
          "price": 12.00,
          "confidence_score": 0.6,
          "rate_of_error": 0.015,
        },
        {
          "epoch_time": 12112230000,
          "price": 13.00,
          "confidence_score": 0.7,
          "rate_of_error": 0.015,
        }
      ]
}
```

It will be "flattened" to become:

```
{
      "ticker_symbol":ticker,
      "model_type":"2",
      "prediction":[
          "epoch_time": 11111100000,
          "price": 12.00,
          "confidence_score": 0.6,
          "rate_of_error": 0.015,
          "epoch_time": 12112230000,
          "price": 13.00,
          "confidence_score": 0.7,
          "rate_of_error": 0.015,
      ]
}
```

Essentially although `prediction` is formatted as a `json` object with nested data, it will be transformed by `requests.post()` to become a `key:[value]` pair.