# Python requests PUT request with json parameter fails and data parameter succeeds

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

**Problem**

I've looked at some of the documentation about the `json` and `data` parameters and the differences between them. I think I understand the difference, best explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188244/what-is-the-difference-between-the-data-and-json-named-arguments-with-reques), in my opinion.

However, I have a specific request that fails on `PUT` using `json`, but fails using `data`, and I'm not sure why. Can someone clarify why this is the case? Could it be that there is a list in the payload?

**Context**

I have `requests==2.28.0` installed. Below is the code that submits the `PUT` requests to an API for PagerDuty, the incident management software, one using `data` (successful) and one using `json` (failing). Otherwise they are identical.

The weird thing is that [their examples](https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/b3A6Mjc0ODE0OA-merge-incidents) use the `json` parameter.

```
payload = f'{{"source_incidents": [{{"id": "{child_incident_id}", "type": "incident_reference"}}]}}'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Accept': "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2",
    'From': email,
    'Authorization': f"Token token={read_write_api_token}"
    }

response = requests.put(f'https://api.pagerduty.com/incidents/{parent_incident_id}/merge', data=payload, headers=headers)

print("response: ", response)
```

Result: `response:  <Response [200]>`

```
payload = f'{{"source_incidents": [{{"id": "{child_incident_id}", "type": "incident_reference"}}]}}'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Accept': "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2",
    'From': email,
    'Authorization': f"Token token={read_write_api_token}"
    }

response = requests.put(f'https://api.pagerduty.com/incidents/{parent_incident_id}/merge', json=payload, headers=headers)

print("response: ", response)
```

Result: `response:  <Response [400]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payload is a string while [`json`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) parameter takes a dictionary. That's the whole point of the `json` argument (you don't have to encode it yourself):

> If you need that header set and you don’t want to encode the `dict` yourself, you can also pass it directly using the `json` parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically:

You should pass a dictionary if you want to use the `json` parameter:

```
payload = {
    "source_incidents": [
        {
            "id": child_incident_id,
            "type": "incident_reference"
        }
    ]
}
```

which is more readable anyway.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Goodness, you miss obvious things in the thick of it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use json.loads to parse your string:

```
import json
payload = f'{{"source_incidents": [{{"id": "{child_incident_id}", "type": "incident_reference"}}]}}'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Accept': "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2",
    'From': email,
    'Authorization': f"Token token={read_write_api_token}"
    }

response = requests.put(f'https://api.pagerduty.com/incidents/{parent_incident_id}/merge', data=json.loads(payload), headers=headers)

print("response: ", response)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what the requests library does with json data.

- Converts your Python object to JSON using the json encoder.
- Sets the "content-type" header to "application/json".

It is possible to implement it as shown here.

```py
def put(uri, data=None, json=None):
    if json and data:
        raise Exception()
    if json:
        payload = json.dumps(json)
    else:
        payload = data
    ...
```

So the first request returns 200 because you passed valid **JSON OBJECT** through the "data" parameter.

And the second request fails because you passed **STRING** through the JSON that will be dumped with "json.dumps(obj)" for example.
As a result, it would be nothing more than a string, which is also a valid JSON object but not a javascript object.

As shown here, if you pass a string through "json.dumps" and a dictionary, it returns two different values: a string and an object.

```
>>> json.dumps("{}")
'"{}"'
>>> json.dumps({})
'{}'
>>>
```