# I am following a tutorial on Flask but i am getting an encoding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

While running the given code i am getting an error which according to me means that my `put`method is either not returning anything or not returning a `json` format

My Code : I have seprated my code into two modules as follows:

main.py file

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort, fields, marshal_with
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class VideoModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    views = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Video(name = {self.name},views = {self.views}, likes = {self.likes})'


video_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
video_put_args.add_argument(
    'name', type=str, help='name of the video is required', required=True)
video_put_args.add_argument(
    'views', type=int, help='views on the video is required', required=True)
video_put_args.add_argument(
    'likes', type=int, help='likes on the video is required', required=True)

resource_fields = {'id': fields.Integer, 'name': fields.String,
                   'views': fields.Integer, 'likes': fields.Integer}


class Video(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, video_id):
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=video_id).first()
        if not result:
            abort(message='could not find the video with that id')
        return result

    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def put(self, video_id):
        args = video_put_args.parse_args()
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=video_id).first()
        if result:
            abort(message='video id taken')
        video = VideoModel(
            id=video_id, name=args['name'], views=args['views'], likes=args['likes'])
        db.session.add(video)
        db.session.commit()
        return video


api.add_resource(Video, "/video/<int:video_id>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

test.py file

```
import requests

BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"


response = requests.put(
    BASE + f'video/{32}',{"likes": 10353, 'name': 'studywithme for 2 hours', 'views': 12342000})

print(response.json())
```

Output :

```
raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I was expecting my code to return a dictionary as i have wrapped my `put` method with a `@marshall_with` decorator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the \`data\` and \`json\` named arguments with requests.post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188244/what-is-the-difference-between-the-data-and-json-named-arguments-with-reques)

Comment: you send your body urlencoded rather than json encoded. See linked question for details about the difference between the 2

Comment: @njzk2 no, i have tried that but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

It is happening when you are trying put the **same video_id** again this is making the **if condition for result** come **true** and **abort** the request and you have not mentioned the **status code** in ***abort function*** so it is getting error on client side.

I hope this will work :

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort, fields, marshal_with
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class VideoModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    views = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Video(name = {self.name},views = {self.views}, likes = {self.likes})'


video_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
video_put_args.add_argument(
    'name', type=str, help='name of the video is required', required=True)
video_put_args.add_argument(
    'views', type=int, help='views on the video is required', required=True)
video_put_args.add_argument(
    'likes', type=int, help='likes on the video is required', required=True)

resource_fields = {'id': fields.Integer, 'name': fields.String,
                   'views': fields.Integer, 'likes': fields.Integer}


class Video(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, video_id):
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=video_id).first()
        if not result:
            abort(404,message='could not find the video with that id')
        return result

    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def put(self, video_id):
        args = video_put_args.parse_args()
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=video_id).first()
        if result:
            abort(409,message='video id taken')
        video = VideoModel(
            id=video_id, name=args['name'], views=args['views'], likes=args['likes'])
        db.session.add(video)
        db.session.commit()
        return video


api.add_resource(Video, "/video/<int:video_id>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In above code you see i added status code in **abort function**.
this will work just fine.